# WebView2 Edge Extensions feature

Tags: webview2

i've embedded a WebView2 control into an application and it works pretty good.

Now i need to integrate this with Oracle ESSO Logon manager because i need OESSO auto inject credentials.

Oracle provides web extensions for Edge/Chrome/Firefox and it works fine too but i need to install this extension in my WebView2 app by default.

WebView2 does not support extensions yet but does anyone know any workaround?

I tried to make some tricks with userFolder without positive results.

```
var userDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The extensions are supported in CefSharp, DotNetBrowser and, I believe, CefGlue. https://dev.to/dotnetbrowser/chrome-extensions-in-net-web-view-controls-11lm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebView2 doesn't currently support extensions although the feature request is tracked on the [WebView2Feedback project](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/191).

The way extensions are disabled I don't believe there is a work around.